# What does "off of" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

I have read this sentence from *Diary of a Wimpy Kid 4*.

> The teachers have really been cracking down on kids copying off of each other this year.

What does *off of* mean?

Comment: Or right in the first line in the popular song "Knockin' on heaven's door" by Bob Dylan it says: "Mama, take this badge **off of** me".

Comment: It's worth noting that, in this case, _of_ is optional. You could say: "...cracking down on kids copying off each other this year," and the sentence would mean the same thing.

Comment: J.R., you're right. It's unnecessary and seems to be a part of American English in particular.

Comment: @J.R., Tell me if I am wrong. In maximum of the cases where I have come across _off of_ constructs, I observed "off" is part of a phrasal verb, e.g. "Get Off of me; I always interpreted that when _off of_ occurs, it means _off_ is part of the phrasal verb (**Get off** in the example) and _of_ acts as _from_, however the answer here does not support my theory. So am I wrong in this understanding?

Comment: @Mistu4u - Yes, _off_ can be part of phrasal verbs. Moreover, in such cases, the _of_ may be optional (e.g., "Get off me!" vs. "Get off of me!" or "Copy the equation off the board" vs "Copy the equation off of the board"). For more details, you can look at [this list](http://www.google.com/#q=%22copied+off%22&safe=off&start=30&tbm=bks); most seem to omit the _of_, but you can find some where _of_ is included.

Comment: This [proposed duplicate](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/95318/6700) only hazily overlaps this question; it's not completely clear that they're duplicates. Let's err on the side of helpfulness and allow this question to get its own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Off of* in that context means *from*.

So the children are copying from one another and the teachers are trying hard to stop it.

*Off of* is quite informal. It is being used here because it's meant to be a child talking or narrating.

Comment: Teachers would often write things on the board and ask students to copy them off the board and into their notebooks.  It naturally follows that students, once having learned to copy off things, would try copying answers *off of* another person's paper/test.

Comment: In the U.S., I don't think *off of* is any more informal than *off*.

Comment: Merriam-Webster [says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20of) "The *of* is often criticized as superfluous, a comment that is irrelevant because *off of* is an idiom. It is much more common in speech than in edited writing and is more common in American English than in British." So the evidence suggests it's mostly informal and more likely to be criticised.

Answer (score 12):

You get *into* a box. (Although you can also get *in* it, which means the same thing.) Once you have gone *into* it, you are then *in* it.

Similarly, you can get *out of* a box. Once you have gone *out of* it, you are then *outside* it.

In the U.S., *off of* and *off* correspond to *into* and *in*. You can jump *off of* the roof. (You can also jump *off* it; this means the same thing.) Once you have jumped *off of* it, you are then *off* it (but maybe you need to go *into* the hospital; don't try this at home).

The phrase *"off of"* was used in the U.K. in exactly the same way before 1750 or so; for example, in 1724 Daniel Defoe wrote

> and with that he flung himself off of his Horse.

If you look at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+of%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+off+of%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20of%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20of%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) you can see a remarkable drop in the frequency of "off of" in English between 1740 and 1780. It's rebounded more in the U.S. than in the U.K. Possibly some authority declared that it was redundant or ungrammatical in the early 18th century, and people started avoided it in formal writing. Or (since I can't find any such authority) maybe this was just how the language evolved in England.

There seem to be some people who seem to have the idea that *off of* is a recent abomination that has polluted the English language, and that you should only ever use *off* or *from*. Remarkably, considering that *off of* is more common in the U.S., a considerable fraction of these people are Americans. I think these people are wrong, and should be ignored.

Comment: See, for example, [How can I explain to people that the phrase “off of ” is grammatically incorrect](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect), although I mote you previously commented on an answer there. Okay I'll get off of (*from)  your back now.

Comment: I am not sure these people are "wrong". They are simply pointing out that English, as in use today, does not require the redundant second "of" since "jump off" adequately describes the very same thing that "jump off off" supposedly does. People are of course free to do whatever they want: just like redefine "literally" to mean "not literally". What I wonder about (and will google soon) is whether "into" and "onto" used to be "in to" and "on to" at some point. In my mind, "jump into" is subtly different from "jump in", in that the first describes the motion for vividly.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to be aware of.

1) *To copy off* of someone is a phrasal verb meaning that you're copying content from their paper.  This has a different meaning from simply *to copy*, which can be to copy someone's information from anywhere (from online, from a book, and not necessarily from their paper).  The way it's used usually implies that the person is with their work at the time.  *To copy off* someone (without *of*) is also common and carries the same meaning.

2) *Off of* versus *off*:  Few people have retained this awareness, but *off of* is the correct preposition to use with a transitive verb, as in

> We jumped off of the boat and into the water.

Many today would simply say

> We jumped off the boat and in the water.

which is technically incorrect unless we jumped (around) while we were on the boat and also while we were in the water.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Ngram Viewer:
1) "off of" is about twice as common in American English as in British English.

2) "of" is the 10th most common word to follow "off" in American English and slightly lower than the 10th most common in British English. (There are some other differences in words and orders.)

Answer (score -4):

As one stated. It's only ever off, not off of.

You can have off of in a sentence but never together.

Eg. I jumped off the ladder. I jumped off the top of the ladder.

Comment: You should provide citations to prove that this is the case, or at least a strong argument.

Comment: "Only" and "never" are such strong words, yet a [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22off+of+the+ladder%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) yilelds hundreds of counterexamples – many from [reputable sources](http://www.surrey.ca/city-services/10750.aspx), such formal safety brochures. [Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22off+of+the+ladder%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22off+of+the+ladder%22&tbm=bks), too. (As a footnote, I beleive this is more common in AmE than BrE.)