# what does the word "off" exactly mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There are two "off" in the below sentence, are they both adverb? does "off+of" mean "from"? I am trying to find its meaning in [longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/off_1), but failed, which explanation can the word "OFF" match?

This is all plastic picked up **off** of beaches, every single bit of it," said Pozzi, "So we have processed about 18 tons of garbage **off** of a small area of beach in the last six years. And it could be anywhere in the world. This is a worldwide problem, the plastic pollution issue.

Remark: 
This sentence comes from ：http://www.51voa.com/VOA_Standard_English/animal-sculptures-national-zoo-plastic-ocean-pollution-70348.html

Comment: This [proposed duplicate](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9784/6700) only hazily overlaps this question; it's not completely clear that they're duplicates. Let's err on the side of helpfulness and allow this question to get its own answer. Also, even if they're duplicates, we shouldn't close _both_ of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**off** (variant **off of**) is used in contexts where something is removed or taken from a place or a surface, or (figuratively) from an intangible place.

> I can't get this gunk off of my new shirt.
>
> Where did you get this picture of an eagle attacking a wolf?
>   -- I got it off the internet.
>
> Some news just came in off the wire.
>
> They picked trash off of the beach.
>
> She took the book off the shelf.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In both of those cases, *off of* does mean from. You can replace off of with from.

Adverbs describe how a verb is done, and almost always they end in -ly; think slowly, quickly etc. "Off of" is used as a preposition. This is a word that shows the relationship between a noun and a pronoun. This shows where I/you/he/she is in relation to the noun - think above, below, behind etc.