# What does "off" stand for in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, word-meaning, adverbs

I was watching a youtube video of someone playing a video game called Splinter Cell and saw this piece of dialogue.

"Hmm...work permits, architectural plans...interesting...Zherkezhi has a hardened panic room **off of** his bedroom."

**"off" (adv)**

a. At a certain distance in space or time: *a mile off; a week off*.(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

**"off" (prep)**

21. located apart from: a village off the main road.
    (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

Does it mean it's not in his bedroom but somewhere near it?

Comment: Yes, it means located apart from but next to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used in that way it means that the room adjoins the bedroom. You would need to enter the bedroom to reach it.

Comment: I think a number of pedants might suggest that 'off of' is wrong, and should be 'off'. I stopped being one of those when I found 'off of' in Pepys' diary.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey OED sense 13 of  *off* deals with instances where it is followed by a preposition, and 13b deals specifically with "off of". The heading states: *Followed by of. In later use colloquial (nonstandard) and regional.* Examples date from the 15C. Only 3 relate to post-WW2. This is one of them: *F. Norman Guntz i. 15   I got hold of this very very old typewriter off of a friend of mine.*. Clearly this is colloquial - you and I have heard people say that - but it is not something you will any longer find in the Times or the New Statesman,

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/what-does-off-of-mean).

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20of) says "off of" is a two-word preposition that means "off".

In this context, it has this definition of "off"

> **1 a** —used as a function word to indicate physical separation or distance from a position of rest, attachment, or union
> *// a path off the main walk*

So it means the panic room is directly connected to his bedroom.